# Kafka :Confluent Schema Registry - Consumer process

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

As per my understanding, Avro schema will be cached in local and consumer will be using from the local cache for deserlization process. In this process if  exception scenario occur like avro schema is not cached in local . What will happen ?
Will it be keep try to read from schema server ? if so , how many times it will be tried ? or any other scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

Messages are written with schema id instead of whole schema. When consumer first reads data, it gets schema id and ask for corresponding schema to schema registry. Consumer will cache schema and do mapping for other messages.

See [schema-ids-in-messages](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/schema_registry_tutorial.html#schema-ids-in-messages)

Comment: Thanks for Your Response . One more quick question  , if fail in Consumer cache the schema in local due to some issue , what will happen . Will it keep send  the schema id  or will it fail ?

Comment: If you use `KafkaAvroDeserializer` in your consumer, you'll get an `SerializationException`. See [serializer](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#serializer)